# Why does setting the user-agent in an unredirected header avoid 403s?

Tags: python, web-scraping, urllib2, user-agent

I've noticed that some webpages that would otherwise return 403 errors when urllib2 is used to fetch them will return content if the user agent is set via the add_unredirected_header function. If the user agent is set via add_header these page will still return 403s, even when the user agent string matches that of a web browser that can successfully load the page. It is only when add_unredirected_header is used to set the user agent that the page content is returned, and in these cases it seems like the user agent can be set to anything. Why does setting the user-agent in an unredirected header avoid 403s?

Comment: You'll have to ask the website operator that. That's not something we can answer; all the function does is set a header that won't be using for requests folliwing a 301 / 302 response.

Comment: It is not a single website that this happens on. So far this has happened on 3/3 websites that I've tested (on different domains).

Comment: Without your code and specific websites, this is not something we can answer, I am afraid.

Comment: Here are a couple examples: http://www.myfoxdetroit.com/ http://www.knoe.com/

Comment: The two sites use the same CMS to render; this is an issue with that CMS it appears. Both sites use http://www.worldnow.com/

Comment: Interesting, worldnow seems to be quite popular among the set of sites I'm analyzing. However, it doesn't account for everything. Here is a wordpress site that behaves in the same way: http://www.radioiowa.com/

Comment: *All `add_unredirected_header()` does* is keep a separate set of headers. These are used *everywhere* normal headers are used, *except* for when handling a redirect. In that case the default User-Agent would be used. E.g. unredirected header values trump 'regular' headers.

Comment: But if a site responds differently when using a user-agent for redirects that's weird, but nothing specific to Python's `urllib2`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [known bug of python](http://bugs.python.org/issue2756). 
See [issue2756: urllib2 add_header fails with existing unredirected_header](http://uthcode.blogspot.jp/2008/08/issue2756-urllib2-addheader-fails-with.html)  for a longer explanation.